Change command which works in cmd.exe to work in powershell.exe
I have a command which works without issue in cmd.exe:
%TESTING_INSTALLATION_PATH%\\client\\batch.exe --log-level=error --run %CI_BUILDS_DIR%\\autotest\\jobs\\clear.py

But it doesn't work in PowerShell like this:
$TESTING_INSTALLATION_PATH\\client\\batch.exe --log-level=error --run $CI_BUILDS_DIR\\autotest\\jobs\\clear.py

But received this:
строка:1 знак:30
+ $TESTING_INSTALLATION_PATH\\client\\batch.exe --log-level=error  ...
+                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token "\\client\\batch.exe" ........................
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken


Laes start by correcting this: %TESTING_INSTALLATION_PATH%\\client\\batch.exe which should be %TESTING_INSTALLATION_PATH%\client\batch.exe. As for the rest, we do not know why or if the arguments should use double backward slashes or single, because we do not know anything about the executable batch.exe. You need to [Edit] your question to submit a [mcve]. We need to be able to reproduce your issue with working examples, so you should provide the code which creates the variables prior to the problematic command.



%TESTING_INSTALLATION_PATH%, for instance, is a cmd.exe-format reference to an environment variable; the equivalent PowerShell expression is therefore: $env:TESTING_INSTALLATION_PATH - see the conceptual about_Environment_Variables help topic.

For syntactic reasons, invoking executables whose name or path is quoted and/or contains variable references requires use of the call operator, &.

For background information, see this answer.


Finally, \ is not special, neither in cmd.exe nor in PowerShell, so there is no need to escape it as \\; cmd.exe's escape char. is ^, whereas PowerShell's is `, the so called backtick.


Therefore:
# NOTE:
#  & to invoke a path containing variable references.
#  $env: to reference environment variables
#  Single \ only.
& $env:TESTING_INSTALLATION_PATH\client\batch.exe --log-level=error --run $env:CI_BUILDS_DIR\autotest\jobs\clear.py

